# Cleaning categorical data with Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, fuzzy-comparison

I have a data set that looks like this (see below). I want to create a new column that that holds the value 'NASA' when 'NASA' appears in the 1st column either by itself or as part of a larger string. How can I do this for a pandas data frame in python?

Thanks!

| index | selection |
| --- | --- |
| NASA- 16 | 51 |
| NASA- 12 | 39 |
| NASA- 8 | 38 |
| NASA- 13 | 38 |
| NASA- 9 | 34 |
| NASA- 10 | 32 |
| NASA- 15 | 30 |
| NASA- 14 | 28 |
| NASA- 17 | 27 |
| NASA- 18 | 26 |
| 1990 NASA group | 25 |
| NASA- 11 | 23 |
| NASA Astronaut Group 8 | 20 |
| NASA- 5 | 19 |
| NASA- 19 | 18 |
| NASA-8 | 18 |
| NASA-9 | 16 |
| 1978 NASA group | 15 |
| 1996 NASA group | 15 |
| TsPK-8 | 15 |
| NPOE-4 | 15 |
| TsPK-2 | 14 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.where` with `str.contains` to check whether your index column has 'NASA' in it. Note that you can use `case=False` to make the search case insensitive:

```
df['new_col'] = np.where(df['index'].str.contains('nasa',case=False),'NASA',"")

df
Out[11]: 
                     index  selection new_col
0                 NASA- 16         51    NASA
1                 NASA- 12         39    NASA
2                  NASA- 8         38    NASA
3                 NASA- 13         38    NASA
4                  NASA- 9         34    NASA
5                 NASA- 10         32    NASA
6                 NASA- 15         30    NASA
7                 NASA- 14         28    NASA
8                 NASA- 17         27    NASA
9                 NASA- 18         26    NASA
10         1990 NASA group         25    NASA
11                NASA- 11         23    NASA
12  NASA Astronaut Group 8         20    NASA
13                 NASA- 5         19    NASA
14                NASA- 19         18    NASA
15                  NASA-8         18    NASA
16                  NASA-9         16    NASA
17         1978 NASA group         15    NASA
18         1996 NASA group         15    NASA
19                  TsPK-8         15        
20                  NPOE-4         15        
21                  TsPK-2         14
```